# Laradock error on Docker on ventura - requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock

I have been running successfully Laradock in a container on Docker Desktop on my old MacBook Pro with Monterrey.  I recently got a new MacBook Pro M2 Silicon with Ventura installed on.  So I first upgraded my old Mac to Ventura, backuped on Time Machine and restored on the new Mac.  The version of Docker Desktop was not compatible, so I upgraded to the newer version of Docker 4.18.0.

I backed up my previous laradock folder in Sites, I launched Docker, then in the terminal I ran the following command at root level (Sites).  Everything seems to run smoothly (laradock container up & running in Docker) except the mailhog & apache2 errors at the end.

```
cd Sites
git clone https://github.com/Laradock/laradock.git
cd laradock
cp .env.example .env
docker-compose up -d apache2 mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace mailhog

Container laradock-mailhog-1  
Container laradock-redis-1 
Container laradock-docker-in-docker-1 
Container laradock-mysql-1  
Container laradock-mysql-1 
! mailhog The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested 
Container laradock-phpmyadmin-1
Container laradock-workspace-1 
Container laradock-php-fpm-1 
Container laradock-apache2-1 
! apache2 The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
```

I look at similar issues but can not find one to solve my problem...

I tried adding `platform: linux/amd64` in the docker-compose.yml file... no effect, running the command `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64`... no effect...

The problem is that I am not sure I understand...  please help.